# AJAX Truncating "00" string to "0"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

So I'm passing over a value of "00" using ajax and for some reason when my WebMethod receives the string, it is only "0"  How can I ensure this truncation doesn't happen?

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost//Scripts/test.aspx/test',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify('{"tivId":"' +
        $(e.relatedTarget).data('id') +
        '","lotId":"' +
        <%= LotId() %> 
        '"}'),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response) {
        SetSuccessModal();
    },
    failure: function(response) {
        alert(response.d);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the code please.

Comment: you will need to check for the length for example is length is <2 then you know that the value returned can be anything from `1..9` so you could check using an And condition to see if value .Contains("0")` and if so change the string from `0` to `"00"`

Comment: check LotId() and everywhere that data come.It's possible some where you send or receive integer data or some where you convert to integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add some symbols tru:

```
"|00|"
```

And then remove them in webMethod

```
param.replace("|","");
```

This is a temporal quick solution, of course, is better if you can catch why this is happening.

Additional to this, maybe the date types could cause issues here, in example... int x = 00;// This will be stored as 0

Comment: It seems to be truncating that to "|0|" before it's even sent to the webmethod

Comment: Then, i think your functions are returning an integer value. You can also try to use ".toString()"

Answer (score -1):

It's impossible to say for sure without any code, but the string will probably be converted into a integer somewhere before transit.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited the code.  So it would be converted to an Int and then back to a string?